# c# mongo dbstats datasize changes type?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get the dataSize from a mongo database

```
        var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument { { "dbstats", 1} });
        var dbstats = ResultDatabase.RunCommand(command);

        var TotalRecordSize = dbstats["dataSize"].AsDouble;
```

This worked when my database was really full, but after clearing all records from the database, it was failing.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonInt32' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDouble'
```

I changed it to be

```
var TotalRecordSize = dbstats["dataSize"].AsInt32;
```

which worked fine for a while, then I started getting

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDouble' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonInt32'
```

So what datatype can I use?  Why does the DATATYPE change?  I understand not being able to put a double value into an int32, but why can't I cast an int32 into a double?

Comment: `after clearing it` What do you mean by that?

Comment: After I cleared all records from the database

Comment: Try using ToDouble instead of AsDouble. The difference is ToDouble will convert the Int32 to double, which is valid. AsDouble only tries to cast which fails.

Comment: @Aman B -- yes that is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ToDouble` instead of `AsDouble`. The difference is `ToDouble` will convert the `Int32` to double, which is valid. `AsDouble` only tries to cast which fails